# Check availability of user id from the database

Tags: asp.net

I have a forgot password page in which  i need to ask from the user his user id to provide him his password from the database and it is working but what to do if anyone enters any wrong user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do `SELECT` to check if that records exists and proceed if so.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that there's a certain measure of risk in this.  If you always respond with a message saying that the User ID is incorrect, then that can be used to guess User IDs in your system.  An attacker can brute-force this form with variations of common names and end up with a sizable list of your users.  For any given account, that gives them half of the information needed to login as that user.

I would recommend that you display a message saying that an email has been sent to the email address for that account with instructions to reset the password (which includes a time-sensitive key required for the reset), regardless if the User ID was found in the system or not.  If they don't get the email, they can always try again (assuming the first attempt included a typo in the User ID).  If they don't actually know their User ID, there can be another form to recover that by entering their email address (behaves in a similar manner to this form, always showing success on the form and just sending the email where applicable).

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform following 3 steps to ensure tight security.

1) Based on the userid fetch the user information from database. If the information is null then send an error to the user, saying invalid UserId.

2) a) If you have registration of EmailId at the time of user creation, then send the password to the registered mail.
   b) If you don't have registration of EmailId then ask and match the security question selected at the time of user registration.

3) If possible try to combine the a) & b) points of point 2) for more enhanced security.

Answer (score 1):

Simply return a message stating they have entered an incorrect user id.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what do you do if they give you the valid ID of another user entirely, then I'm assuming you're doing something quite unsafe with the password you're recovering (you aren't just showing them the password are you?) - most systems like this will email you the password, at least affording the security that only the associated email account will ever be given the password.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = inputhere

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  // found it
}
else
{
  // doesn't exist
}
```

Is that what you were looking for?